# Rails skip nil values in the id of the path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trucks has_many :checklist and Checklist belong_to :truck 
In the main page I create a table that show every truck name and the date of the last checklist with a link to the last Checklist.
All works perfect with the old data but when I add a new Truck there's no checklist of this new Truck and the main page broke , there's a way to make an exception when the truck doesn't have checklists

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"checklists", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

```
<td>
    <a href="<%= truck_path(truck.id) %>">
        <%= truck.name %>
    </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="<%= checklist_path(truck&.checklist&.last&.id) %>">
        <%= truck.checklist.last&.created_at&.strftime("%d-%m") %>
    </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to add more logic in the view but this work for me

```
<% if truck.checklist.present? %>
    <a href="<%= checklist_path(truck.checklist.last.id) %>">
        <%= truck.checklist.last&.created_at&.strftime("%d-%m") %>
    </a>
<% end %>
```